# Why does (find-if #'consp '('notdefinedsymbol)) => 'NOTDEFINEDSYMBOL?

Tags: common-lisp, quote

This code came from the emacs buffer *slime-repl sbcl* :

> CL-USER> (consp 'notdefinedsymbol)
>
> NIL
>
> CL-USER> (find-if #'consp '('notdefinedsymbol))
>
> 'NOTDEFINEDSYMBOL

If consp returns nil then why does find-if act as if consp returns a true value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `(consp 'notdefinedsymbol)` `consp` in operator position is a symbol for the `#'consp` function and thus it's argument `(quote notdefinedsymbol)`, abbrevated as just `'notdefinedsymbol` needs to be evaluated before application. A `(quote x)` evalues to the data `x` so in our case the argument becomes the symbol `notdefinedsymbol`. It is NOT a `cons` but a `symbolp` and thus the result is `nil`

With the second you have `(find-if #'consp '('notdefinedsymbol))` and since `find-if` is a fucntion it evaluates its arguments. `#'consp` evaluates to the function object and `'('notdefinedsymbol)` which is short for `(quote ((quote notdefinedsymbol)))` is evaluates. As always it evaluated to its argument which is `((quote notdefinedsymbol))`. It is a list with one element which itself is a list with two elements, the symbols `quote` and `notdefinedsymbol`. Since `(consp '(quote notdefinedsymbol) ; ==> t` `find-if` evaluates to `(quote notdefinedsymbol)` and some CL printers will abbreviate a list of two elements where the first element is `quote` with the same manner as the reader macro and print `'notdefinedsymbol` but it still is a list of two elements since it is not code, but data.

Your mistake is of course that you nest quotes. If you had done it like this you get your expected result:

```
(find-if #'consp '(notdefinedsymbol)) ; ==> nil
```

Answer (score 1):

`(consp 'a)` - function arguments get evaluated first. So we have: `'a` evaluates to: `a`. And that is an atom, thus `NIL`.

`(find-if #'consp '('a))` also evluates arguments first. But for the first argument of the list, it tests whether `'a` is a cons. It is, because that is `(quote a)` (only the outer `'` of the list is evaluated, the inner in front of `a` not, therefore `'a`.

`a = notdefinedsymbol`.

Answer (score 1):

Your call: `(find-if #'consp '('not-defined-symbol))` is the same as (i. e. is expanded by the reader to) `(find-if (function consp) (quote ((quote not-defined-symbol))))`.  The argument `(quote ((quote not-defined-symbol)))` is evaluated to the list `((quote not-defined-symbol))` (i. e. a list containing a list containing the two symbols `quote` and `not-defined-symbol`).  `Find-if` goes through that outer list, tests the inner, which is a cons, with `consp`, which says *true*, and returns it.

What you wanted to do is most likely: `(find-if #'consp '(not-defined-symbol))`, which *is the same as* `(find-if (function consp) (quote (not-defined-symbol))`.  Note: no nested quote.

Look at [the docs for `quote`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_quote.htm#quote) and [the CLHS chapter about evaluation](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_.htm) for a better understanding.